# pullback and pushforward examples

Tags: differential-geometry

Where can I find some simple examples of pullbacks and pushforwards between manifolds. Specifically examples that show the details of the computations.

Comment: Pullbacks and pushforwards of what: vector fields? differential forms? vector bundles? other?

Comment: Of maps between manifolds.

Comment: We push forward/pull back objects defined on manifolds *by* maps between manifolds. You can pull back/push forward a map by another map but this is just the composition - I'm guessing you're thinking about something else?

Comment: Given the simplicity of the question's wording, I think it's very likely OP was simply asking about the canonical pushforward of the tangent bundle (of some simple manifold) induced by a map (preferably a simple one) and ditto for the pullback of the cotangent bundle.

Comment: I know its been more than 5 years since this question has been asked but i hope this answer will help others, there are plenty of numerical examples in the book A "Visual Introduction to Differential Forms and Calculus on Manifolds (2019, Springer International Publishing)" by Fortney, J.P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [An Introduction to Differential Geometry
through Computation](https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1000&context=oer_textbooks) by Mark Fels.